# AspNetCoreModule is required instead of AspNetCoreModuleV2 for my .Net core 3.1 app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have created a .net core 3.1.0 app and deployed it in IIS. I have installed web server hosting bundle 3.1.16. In IIS modules, I can see  AspNetCoreModuleV2 and web.config also aspnetcore module is  AspNetCoreModuleV2 and hostingmodel is inprocess.
[image]
[image]
But the app is not running and it's showing 500.19 error.
[image]
If I install web server hosting bundle 1.0.16, it will resolve the problem. But as per my understanding, hosting bundle 1.x version is only needed for .net core 1.x apps. Could anyone please help me to understand this issue?

Comment: Have you installed `Microsoft .NET Core X - Windows Server Hosting` correctly?

Comment: Yes installed Microsoft .NET Core 3.1.16 windows server hosting. But I need to install Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.16 windows server hosting bundle also to work my 3.1 app

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was already installed 1.X hosting bundle and also installed 3.x hosting bundle. Then I uninstalled 1.x version. After that my app was not working.
Then I uninstalled 3.x version and installed 3.x again. It resolved my problem.